# How to create a document Excel with the 10 previous measurements before a certain date in Python

Tags: python, excel, save, subset

I am finding some troubles in doing a work: I have a dataset containing some measurements over time. I needed to extract the 10 previous values before a certain date, and the 10 following values after a certain date. And that is done, doing the following basically:

```
N = wanted date of interest
df_after = df.loc[df.date_time > N ].head(10)
df_bef = df.loc[df.date_time < N ].tail(10)
```

It's here where troubles begin for me: I tried to put them in a column wise order and then save them in a excel file, but there is always a problem. I got that the result is a series and that is no good for what I need to do.
I do not care about format, sheets, names of the columns and so on I just want an ordered table (possible by columns each of which is df_after and df_bef and the results below).
Can someone help?

I want df_bef and df_after and their values obviously to be saved in a excel document in columns